# Moq First() Last() and GetEnumerator() wierdness

Tags: linq, moq, enumerable

I am Moqing my Route Parts from a 
`rps = new List``... (3 Route Parts)`

and `Moqing GetEnumerator()` for my Route as below

`route.Setup(ro => ro.GetEnumerator()).Returns(rps.GetEnumerator());`

but the `Moq` fails in the following code with "Sequence contains no elements" on the call to `Last()`

```
o.Route.Any(rp => rp.IsNonTowLocation && 
rp != o.Route.First() && 
rp != o.Route.Last())
```

Looking at `First()` `Last()` in the immediate windows I find the values change if I execute `First()` `Last()` multiple times. Its as if the `MoveNext()` gets called but not `Reset()` and the Enumerable it totally confused. Has anyone experienced this with `Moq` and found a solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've setup your GetEnumerator so that it returns the same enumerator instance every time.

```
route.Setup(ro => ro.GetEnumerator()).Returns(rps.GetEnumerator());
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var enumerator = rps.GetEnumerator()
route.Setup(ro => ro.GetEnumerator()).Returns(enumerator);
```

If you want a new enumerator on every call, then you need to pass Returns a lambda expression:

```
route.Setup(ro => ro.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => rps.GetEnumerator());
```

The lambda will get called every time GetEnumerator() is called - so `First()` and `Last()` should then work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :-) Your answer made me think about how the enumerators are used. Will First() and Last() be evaluated as consants by the Expression parser or will they get re-evaluated on every RoutePart of the route?

Comment: yes - re-evaluated each time until the first match is found (at which point `Any` can return)

Comment: I can't get this to work: the error I get is - Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.GetEnumerator()

Comment: probably best for you to ask as a new (VB?) question